# Redis goes down while executing keys command from nodejs for searching a pattern

Tags: node.js, redis

In redis we have data close to 9 - 10 million i.e. dbsize . We have lots of different types of keys in it. Assume like a.b.c , a.b.d , a.d.c , a.d.e . So I need to fetch all the keys with pattern ' a.*.c ' or ' a.b.* ' etc .
When I try to fetch data using command 'keys a.*.c' , it hampers performance of redis in big way due to huge amount of data.

Do we have any other way to fetch data from redis based on such patterns. Idea is to fetch data very quickly.

I tried with scan command but it takes a lot of time i.e. like 3-4 minutes (if you know how to use scan effectively that will also help).

In our nodejs application we have used 'redis' npm package to access redis.

Comment: There is no way to do it besides those two methods, apart from a module based implementation. The module examples have a non blocking scan implementation.